# Unchained transaction mode

Tags: c#, .net, sybase

Am getting this error when I run a piece of code under .net transaction using

> tran = connection.BeginTransaction();

Error=> "Stored procedure 'pr_xxxxx' may be run only in unchained transaction mode The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode".

How can I set chained/unchained mode in transaction?. Am using ODBC connection and my database is sybase

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the SET CHAINED OFF command before you execute your procedure. Also you may need to make sure auto commit is disabled by setting the DbCommand.Transaction property and manually calling the Commit() method on your transaction object.